# Identification of dynamic grid with extjs code in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I have a dynamic grid populating with Extjs code, for which the element IDs are not visible. Can some one let me know how to find the element i am using selenium webdriver to code. Thanks in advance.

1. I have added HTML code as i was unable to paste as an image. This HTML is the grid area with which the dynamic grid is displayed.
2. No Element is available in the HTML except for body elements

> ```
> <div id="ext-comp-1117" class=" x-panel">
> <div id="ext-gen127" class="x-panel-bwrap">
> <div id="ext-gen128" class="x-panel-tbar x-panel-tbar-noheader">
> <div id="ext-comp-1118" class="x-toolbar x-small-editor x-toolbar-layout-ct">
> <table class="x-toolbar-ct" cellspacing="0">
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td class="x-toolbar-left" align="left">
> <table cellspacing="0">
> <tbody>
> <tr class="x-toolbar-left-row"></tr>
> </tbody>
> </table>
> </td>
> <td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right"></td>
> </tr>
> </tbody>
> </table>
> </div>
> </div>
> <div id="ext-gen129" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader"></div>
> </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments yet, but could you please provide more information:
1. Sample of html?
2. elements not visible but are they present in html?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ext.ComponentQuery.query to fetch the id at runtime.